# Allure .Organizing tests in one Feature

Tags: automated-tests, allure

Could you please help me with two questions regarding organizing tests and using Allure's "feature" tags?

1. If I have a few different tests but I need all of them to be included into one feature, do I have to write `@Features("My Feature")` annotation above each test method? Is there a way to write the `@Features("My Feature")` annotation once and include all required tests in it?
2. If I have a few logically separated classes with my `@Test` methods, is there an easy way to call all required tests from one TestSuite class in order to simply manage test queue?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can write annotation `@Feature` once per class. But are you really need such feature? Maybe you should think a bit more and split your tests using some other way?
2. Allrue is not a test framework, it just a report tool. Allure does not run tests. To answer this part of question I need to know more about test framework you use, your environment (Ant, Maven, Jenkins, Teamcity etc)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for misunderstanding. I'm using Testng and maven and it seems that I've solved my issue with test organizing. But maybe you could provide me with some project examples where "@Features" and "@Stories" annotations are used in clear and proper way?